# Vertex displacement through shader in Babylon.js not updating mesh's shadow

Tags: babylonjs

I'm morphing an object's vertices using a vertex shader in Babylon.js. The morphed object looks great, but I can't figure out a way to cause the object's shadow to update as well.

I know in Three.js there is a customDepthMaterial for a mesh where you can pass in the same custom vertex shader and correctly update the object's shadow, but is there something similar in Babylon.js? I have to use Babylon for this project.